# FlashDevelop settings

Tags: flashdevelop

I've recently upgraded to **FlashDevelop 4**, which of course has reverted all the settings I had previously to the original.

The problem I'm having is that I can't find where in the new settings window it gives me the option to turn off the auto-space it inserts before brackets, curly brackets etc.

ie it's automatically making these:

```
if(2 > 1)
public function get thing():Thing{ return _thing; }
```

into:

```
if (2 > 1)
public function get thing():Thing { return _thing; }
```

It's driving me insane and actually causing me to stop using FlashDevelop temporarily. If I could turn off the auto-formatting stuff altogether like I could in previous versions that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools > Program Settings > ASCompletion

Under the "Helpers" settings you will find "Always Add Space After". By default it will contain if/for/while/do/catch/with. Remove the keywords you don't want to get autoformatted and the rest is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Ah, everything I need is under the Helpers section - thank you.